# URL Rewriting for user profiles

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using a hash value to prevent spam and direct access to user profiles with changing ID numbers. This is a unique integer value given user once when they registered, stored in database and never change.

Profile links look like this:

```
example.com/profile.php?id=xxx&hash=xyz
```

I want to rewrite URL with user nicknames, like this:

```
example.com/nickname
```

But how can I do it when using a hash value in URL? I couldn't find a sample for this!

Comment: So, you want Apache to query a database every time example.com/nickname is loaded in order to retrieve the hash value so that it can rewrite appropriately? Something like this may be what you're looking for: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbm

Comment: Yes, i check the value every profile request. I will look at docs, thank you

Comment: I think you should rewrite your quetcion. Important points are : what is the url visible to end users and use in browsers? Do you want a Redirect (back to browser) to occur or simply a server-side only mapping? Why don't you want to hadle that in your app server but in the http server?

Comment: @regilero My intension is vanity url. I know some sites using hash thing. If user have a nickname, browser show vanity URL, if not you see user's link like example.com/profile.php?id=xxx&hash=xyz in adress bar. I have no idea how they handle this, it's not a rewrite at all?

Comment: In addition, everyone has a unique nickname in my site and i thought my only need is rewrite URL. There are many tutorial about this, but all samples show how you can rewrite profile.php?id=xxx . This is why i am asking here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well:

You want to provide to the end user several url:

- `/profile.php?id=<id>&hash=<hash>`
- `/<nickname>`

They would all be available but the 2nd one would be the preffered way.

there is a problem with the `/<nickname>` type of url, if a nickname is "foo/bar" or "index.php" or "admin", etc the problem is that some nicknames may cover some other valid urls. So at least a better format for vanity url would be:

- `/nick/<nickname>` or `/user/<nickname>`

If you do not want that you'll have to ensure that nicknames will never match any valid path to any other asset.

Then you'll quite certainly have to handle special characters in nicknames, spaces, "/", chineses utf16 chars, windows specific encoding, etc. This usually targets the application server as the best tool for handling the nickname and finding the real user page to show.

Now let's take back the first url format :  `/profile.php?id=<id>&hash=<hash>`, you use the hash to avoid direct access to user profile by altering the id. And you said every user have a nickname. I would say why not simply only using the vanity format and forbid direct access to the profile.php script with an id? You could hanlde all user profile acess internally and never provide such entry... anyway, let's say you still want to be able to access a user profile by id.

This access url is generated by your application. Your application is adding the hash after the url when providing the link, (maybe the hash is a salted hash based on the nickname?). So your application can store for each user the user hash. And then in profile.php you always check that the hash is the right one for this id. All this is managed in your application, not in the http server (apache). The http server and his rewriting tools is, in my humble opinion, not the right tool to make the match, it cannot easily match your outgoing links and alter them, it cannot easily catch your ongoing links and transform them in the right profile.php+id+hash form.

So the only rewriteRule I would use is one catching nickname based entries and sending them internally to a profile redirector script in your application. Something like:

```
RewriteRule  ^/nick/(.*)$ /profile-by-nick.php?nick=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then inside this php script you can do what you want to provide the same task as in profile.php. With a well written php app it's quite easy to provide internal redirection inside the application, do not send a real http 302 redirection on the profile.php script. use functions, classes, etc.

If really you want apache to directly send the right profile.php?id=&hash= url to your application (maybe because your php code was written by a poney :-) ) then you could check RewriteMap as suggested by @David Ravetti and get an external script running as a daemon and providing the nickname->id+hash mapping to apache. But it seems really more complex, not the right place to handle it. This script will need rights to load you database, and informations on table structures that your application already have.

Comment: Thank you for all informations. Honestly i never thought about what if a user choose a specific directory as a nickname, good point. I checked RewriteMap, it's so complicated to me. Would you like to give me little information about how can i forbid direct access to the profile.php? That's mean also more security? I am thinking change the way prevent spam, let's assume allowing user send 100 messages per hour, then people cannot spam on users' comment walls.

Comment: there're plenty of ways to prevent access to a script, one of them is putting this script out of the document root, others may imply mod-rewrite or Redirect instrctions like in: `RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/profile\.php$`